# In Oracle, how to globally enable parallel execution?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

In Oracle 11g, is there a way to tell the database to use parallel execution whenever possible by setting a flag etc, rather than using PARALLEL hints with every SQL statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer: Yes. Unfortunately it is not quite a simple as that, as if you want to enable parallelism, then you are obviously concerned about performance, and it is [extremely tunable](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10736/usingpe.htm#i1007196).

Start with `alter system set paralllel_automatic_tuning=true scope=spfile;` then restart. This will have Oracle do what it thinks is best. There are many other parameters to set (e.g. [parallel_execution_message_size](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10736/usingpe.htm#i1008295)) and you will need to experiment to find the best. Be careful with this; it is easy when you start out with parallel query to get carried away in benchmarking then discover in the "real world" a few queries fly but the overall throughput of the system actually *decreases* as some sessions are starved of CPU or the system is forced into swap. The documentation warns:

> When concurrent users have too many
>   query server processes, memory
>   contention (paging), I/O contention,
>   or excessive context switching can
>   occur. This contention can reduce
>   system throughput to a level lower
>   than if parallel execution were not
>   used.

So I strongly advise putting some limits in place, e.g. with [resource consumer groups](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10739/dbrm.htm#sthref3107).

Also for any table you can do `ALTER TABLE table_name PARALLEL (DEGREE x);` where x is a number, 4 or 8 might be good places to start.

Comment: Thanks Gaius! About your last point.. I tried doing an `alter table tablename parallel;`. After this I tried seeing the query plan for an insert statement on the table, and it was not parallel. What exactly then this alter table statement do?

Comment: Oracle is still being "intelligent" in the query optimizer; if there's not enough work in your `INSERT` to justify spinning up parallel query slaves, it won't. What happens if you do `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT (...)` for a few million rows? (I guess you would also want `PARALLEL` set on the table you are selecting from).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want the parallel_automatic_tuning=true setting.